# JavaScript DOM Event Function

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom

I'm trying to implement a JavaScript function for a HTML page that simply reveals text on mouse down. I want to apply this multiple times so don't want to have to create a function for each event.

The below code works fine...

```
function showSkillInfo() {
    if (skill1Info.style.display === 'none') {
        skill1Info.style.display = 'grid';
    } else {
        skill1Info.style.display = 'none';
    };
};
skill1.onmousedown = showSkillInfo;
```

But this block of code seems to have no response...

```
function showSkillInfo2(skill) {
    if (skill.style.display === 'none') {
        skill.style.display = 'grid'
    } else {
        skill.style.display = 'none'
    };
};
skill1.onmousedown = showSkillInfo2(skill1Info);
```

Can anyone tell me why the second function isn't working the same way the first function is?

Comment: can you add your relevant HTML and reproduce the problem? you are using 2 different examples here, the first one uses `skill1Info` which I assume was already defined outside your function, and the second example sends the element as an argument `skill`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] showing the second block not working. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to include both the JavaScript and HTML in a runnable snippet.

Comment: `onmousedown` takes a function reference. In the first block, you are specifying `showSkillInfo`, which is a function reference. In the second block, you are specifying `showSkillInfo2(skill1Info)`, which is undefined, since `showSkillInfo2` does not return anything. You would need to change it to `showSkillInfo2.bind(skill1Info, skill1Info)` or `function() { showSkillInfo2(skill1Info); }` for it to work correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assigning .onmousedown with () runs the function when assigned , work arounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246502/assigning-onmousedown-with-runs-the-function-when-assigned-work-arounds)

Comment: can't you just add an `eventListener` to all elements you want to affect with the  `onmousedown` instead?

Comment: [Don't use on(...) event handling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers), it was the web's first attempt at JS events for HTML pages, almost 30 years ago, and was superseded by [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers#eventtarget.addeventlistener) less than 5 years later and has be the "right" way to handle events ever since. Use that instead. As for the question: because you're calling your function in code block 2 and binding the _result_ of that call, instead of binding the _function_ that needs to run.

Comment: Since it sounds like you have multiple skills that you want to click on you may want to consider [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) which allows you to attach one listener to a containing element (sometimes `document`) and have that listen for events from its child elements as they "bubble up" the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

The `.onmousedown` attribute is a callback function called when a specific event is triggered (mouse down in that case, but all other events work the same way). This means that a reference to a function or a lambda function must be specified for it to work. The first example is indeed a reference to a function and works as expected. The second one, on the other hand, is a call to a function and it is its return value (`undefined`) that will be affected to `skill1.onmousedown`. For it to work as intended, you need to specify a new function that will be called with the right parameter. The best way to do this is using lambda functions, like this:
`skill1.onmousedown = () => showSkillInfo2(skill1Info);`
This way, `skill1.onmousedown` has the value of a function with no parameter, and it can be called when the associated event is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

This line: `skill1.onmousedown = showSkillInfo2(skill1Info);` is being called immediately, before `skill` can be defined, so it doesn't work.

What you'll need to do is put that line within another function and that other function will be assigned as the `mousedown` callback function.

Also, you don't need two classes here. You can just have a default class that is in effect all the time, and then change it to the new class upon `mousedown`.

Lastly, you shouldn't use HTML event attributes to set up events as this is a nearly 30 year old technique from before we had standards. Instead, separate your HTML and JavaScript.

See the comments inline below:

```js
function showSkillInfo(event) {
  // First, determine if the event occured on an element you care to handle
  if(event.target.classList.contains("skill")){
    // Just use the .toggle() method to toggle the use of a class.
    // No if statement needed.
    // event.target references the actual element that triggered the event
    event.target.classList.toggle("grid");
  }
};


// We'll just set up mousedown and mouseup events on a parent element
// of the possible elements that may need to be handled.
// by wrapping your callback inside of another function, you get the
// ability to set up the callback without invoking the "real" code 
// that should wait for the event to happen. You can also pass the 
// automatically provided reference to the event that triggered the
// callback to the function.
document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
  showSkillInfo(event);
});

document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
  showSkillInfo(event);
});
```

```css
.skill {
  color:aqua;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.grid { 
  /* This is sample CSS. Replace with yours.  */
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer <span class="skill">took a galley</span> of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised <span class="skill">in the 1960s</span> with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker <span class="skill">including versions</span> of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```